# Armadillo equivalent for MATLAB operations

Tags: c++, matlab, linear-algebra, armadillo

Hi I am new to armadillo. I am looking for the Armadillo equivalent for the following operation performed in MATLAB:

```
B(B_t>=0) = 1;
B(B_t<0) = -1;
```

Here B and B_t are two matrices having same dimensions.
I can use the armadillo signum function(sign) here but then I need to set all zero elements to one. I am sure this is a simple problem. Your help is appreciated.

Also, can anyone let me know how to set non-contiguous indexes in an armadillo matrix to a particular value?

Thanks.

Comment: Your title and 2nd sentence seem contradictory. What equivalent for what operations are you looking for?

Comment: @Benoit_11 - Most likely they want to find the equivalent Armadillo syntax when the MATLAB syntax has been established.  Reading the entire post, that's what it looks like.  I've modified the body to avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have two matrices A and B of the same dimension you could set all of the elements of A where the corresponding element of B is > 0 to a value with

```
using namespace arma;

// A and B are matrices of the same shape.
mat A = randu<mat>(5,5) - 0.5;
mat B = randu<mat>(5,5) - 0.5;

// Change elements of A where B > 0 to 10.0
A.elem( find(B > 0) ).fill(10.0);
```

Where we have used [find](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#find) to produce a list of indicies that satisfy the desired criteria. [.elem](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat) to then create a view of those elements of A. And finally [.fill](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#fill) to set those elements to the desired value.