# Armadillo equivalent to A(find(A<0)) = 0

Tags: c++, c++11, armadillo

Though my question is similar to an earlier one posted here: [Armadillo equivalent for MATLAB operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950307/armadillo-equivalent-for-matlab-operations)

It is slightly different and so it does not seem to work. I am solving a PDE and to iterate through time with a solution vector soln(Nr,Nt) where Nr is the spatial grid size and Nt, the number of time steps. I am using the following call

```
soln.col(n+1) = solve(A,B*soln.col(n));
```

Numerical error is introduced and we obtain small but not negligible negative numbers which are artificial. I don't want to use find(soln < 0) each pass because the matrix is Nr*Nt. I would prefer to just look at that particular column, but then the syntax `find(soln.col(n+1))<0)` can not be used to adjust that columns elements. Of course I can just use a for loop each iteration and check element-wise, but I this seems like it would be slower (correct me if I am wrong).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [.clean()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#clean) function may work for you here, available with Armadillo 9.600 or later.

```
soln.col(n+1).clean(datum::eps);
```

To clean an entire matrix:

```
soln.clean(datum::eps);
```

.clean() will zero out all elements with an absolute value <= [datum::eps](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#constants).

If you want to zero out all negative numbers, using the [.transform()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#transform) function is one possibility (requires a C++11 capable compiler):

```
vec tmp = solve(A,B*soln.col(n));

tmp.transform( [](double val) { return (val < 0.0) ? 0.0 : val; } );

soln.col(n+1) = tmp;
```

Processing each column directly may also work (haven't tested this):

```
soln.col(n+1).transform( [](double val) { return (val < 0.0) ? 0.0 : val; } );
```

The [solve()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#solve) function will probably take far longer to run than the post-processing anyway.

Comment: Thanks! Both methods work. Interestingly (or not?) they seem to be roughly the same speed as just looping through the whole column and setting negative numbers to 0.